# Is it possible to overlap the status bar with content in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, statusbar

Is it possible for content in a view to overlap the status bar in iOS? I don't want to cover the whole status bar - just have a graphic extend a few pixels into it.

Are there any examples of this in the store now? Or does the HIG prohibit it?

I've seen examples of apps that place their own content in the iOS status bar. Reeder is perhaps the most popular example of this. But in Reeder, the content is contained entirely within the status bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use UIWindow,

```
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UIWindow *overlapView = [UIWindow new];
    overlapView.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    overlapView.frame = app.statusBarFrame; // you can set any size of frame you want
```

P.S. instance of UIWindow is set hidden = YES by default, so you should set hidden = NO when you want to display the overlapView;